# How to get param in jsp file from ajax post

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, request

I use ajax post param in js file:

```
var parData = {"code":_code, "filetype":_type, "reportParam":par_str, "uuid":uuid};
    $.ajax({
          url: _url,
          type: "POST",
          data: parData,
          dataType: 'binary',
          success: function(result) {
            //called when successful

          }
        });
```

in jsp file, I use request.getParameter but it return null

```
String uuid= request.getParameter("uuid");
```

Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: What is the `_url` ?

Comment: _url is my jsp file

Comment: so you're making a ajax request to another jsp file? Why not just use a servlet then? Putting scriptlets in jsps is bad practice.

Comment: yes. I know but I'm not the decider. If I used $.post then I can get parameter with String uuid= request.getParameter("uuid");